# How to upload to Azure blob and create subdirectories by date

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I want to know if its possible to create sub directories by date while uploading a file to Azure blob container.

Example:

```
Directory 1: 2020
Subdirecotry1: 05
Subdirecotry2: 26
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI Azure Storage (blobs) doesn't have subdirectories: just account/container/blob. What might look like a subdirectory is merely a blob name with delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick!

```
#FilePath+TimeDate
$year = (Get-Date -Format yyyy)
$month = (Get-Date -Format MM)
$day = (Get-Date -Format dd)


#Upload
Get-ChildItem -File $FilePath1 -Recurse  | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container 
$container -Blob $year/$month/$day/ -Context $StorageContext
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the container as "2020" and the rest as part of your blob name: "05/26/blob.txt"

PS: Azure Storage doesn't have this concept of subcontainers

Comment: Is this what you mean?

Get-ChildItem -File $File1 -Recurse  | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container 2020 -Blob "05/26/blob.txt" -Context $StorageContext???

Comment: I'm not a powershell expert, but it looks right to me.

Comment: This is not what i am looking for, because i need to use a script to automate this and the sub directories need to be created by date and then the file must be transferred after its created.